# Java structured concurrency

Tags: java, project-loom

**Structured concurrency:**

> a simple principle that states that when the flow of execution splits into multiple concurrent flows, they rejoin in the same code block.

[Source](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/8277129)

Based on this, let's assume I have something like below:

```
//can replace this with Virtual thread
public static void delegateTask() {
    Thread delegator = new Thread(new TaskDeligator());
    delegator.setName("TaskDeligatorThread");
    logger.info("Creating task delegator thread....which will register listeners");
    delegator.start();
}
```

**Question 1:**
I have created a new child thread(*TaskDeligatorThread*) but did not finish/end/rejoin in the same code block i.e. the method *delegateTask()* - does this mean it's not following structured concurrency principle?

**Question 2:**
There might be scenarios where Thread1 wants to delegate some task to a child thread (which Thread1 will create) and Thread1 doesn't need to wait for the output/completion of the child thread. In this case, again I will not finish/end/rejoin the child thread in the code block where the child thread was created. In these kind of scenarios how would I follow structured concurrency?

Comment: My 2c is that if the code which creates the thread has no interest in whether it completes successfully, then structured concurrency is irrelevant.

Comment: Makes sense, @tgdavies. Would that be considered bad practice? Thanks

Comment: It depends what the thread is doing. Perhaps there's some other way that failures are reported, or perhaps failure doesn't matter. It depends.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "within the same code block" is a bit ambiguous.

Strictly speaking, your `main` method could open a StructuredExecutor and make it available to all code in your entire program, such that you're using the library support for structured concurrency but not really using structured concurrency. (This is roughly analogous to using for+switch to write spaghetti code that technically doesn't contain 'goto' but amounts to the same thing.)

Both of your examples do *not* follow the structured concurrency principle, because they involve forking off a task and abandoning it. You can potentially rework them to follow that principle by identifying a higher-level caller that really does depend on that task, and having that higher-level caller manage the StructuredExecutor. Alternatively, you might decide that you don't really want to follow this principle, either in general or in these cases.

The JEP doesn't really explain the concept of structured concurrency in detail, because its main focus is on how it could be supported in Java. If you'd like to understand the concept itself, I'd recommend reading one or both of the blog posts that it links to:

- ["Structured Concurrency", by Martin Sústrik, 2016-02-07](https://250bpm.com/blog:71/)
- ["Notes on structured concurrency, or: Go statement considered harmful", by Nathaniel J. Smith, 2018-04-25](https://vorpus.org/blog/notes-on-structured-concurrency-or-go-statement-considered-harmful/)

(Note: the former is a bit more technical, the latter a bit easier to read.)

Comment: Thank for the blog posts, will take a look @ruakh.

So is it that whenever we make use of listeners `java.util.EventListener` it will never be structured...even though the flow comes back after the listener is registered. In the background there is a thread which is alive and keeps listening for events.

Comment: @srock: I'm not aware of any inherent reason that java.util.EventListener is incompatible with structured concurrency. But I definitely recommend that you read through the second blog post that I linked to (the one by Nathan J. Smith); I don't think I can answer your questions any better than you'll get by reading that post. (That post is arguably the definitive exposition of the concept.)

Answer (score -1):

Based on the definition you provided, structured concurrency emphasizes that concurrent flows of execution should rejoin in the same code block. Let's address your questions:

Question 1: Yes, based on the principle of structured concurrency, creating a child thread (TaskDeligatorThread) within the delegateTask() method and not ensuring it rejoins in the same code block would violate the principle. The structured concurrency principle suggests that the flow of execution should remain organized and coherent, with concurrent flows rejoining in the same code block to maintain clarity and manageability.

Question 2: In scenarios where Thread1 delegates a task to a child thread and doesn't need to wait for its completion, you can still adhere to the structured concurrency principle by ensuring that the child thread rejoins the main thread or completes its task in a controlled manner. One common approach to achieve this is through synchronization mechanisms like join(), where the main thread waits for the child thread to finish its task before proceeding. However, if you specifically don't want Thread1 to wait for the completion of the child thread, you can still structure your code to handle this situation gracefully.

One approach could be to have a mechanism for tracking the lifecycle of child threads and ensuring they complete their tasks before the main thread exits or moves on to other operations. This could involve using higher-level concurrency constructs provided by frameworks or libraries, such as Executors in Java, which manage the lifecycle of threads and provide mechanisms for coordinating their execution.

In summary, while structured concurrency emphasizes rejoining concurrent flows in the same code block, there are ways to handle scenarios where a parent thread delegates tasks to child threads without waiting for their completion. The key is to ensure that the overall flow of execution remains organized and that the lifecycle of all threads is managed appropriately to prevent issues such as resource leaks or unexpected behavior.

Comment: Posting AI-generated answers is [forbidden on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy).